# How to convert variant to string in C++

Tags: c++, variant

I'm new in C++, and I wanted to know how to convert a variant to string:

```
variant<string, int, float> value;

if (!value.empty()) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: `std::get<string>(value)`, see [documetation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get)

Comment: [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is the preferred way to work with `std::variant`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you will need custom code for the different cases...
The following function would do as you want:

```
string stringify(variant<string, int, float> const& value) {
    if(int const* pval = std::get_if<int>(&value))
      return to_string(*pval);
     
    if(float const* pval = std::get_if<float>(&value))
      return to_string(*pval);
    
    return get<string>(value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `std::holds_alternative` method to check if the value is a string, and then `std::get` to retrieve it:

```
if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(value)) {
    std::cout << std::get<std::string>(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the object of type `T` from a `std::variant`:

```
std::variant<T, T1, T2> myVariant;

try
{
    auto& myT = std::get<T>(myVariant);
}
catch (std::bad_variant_access const& ex)
{
    ...
}
```

The `try-catch` is only necessary if you try to get a type that doesn't exist in the variant. Alternatively, you can check if an object of that type is contained in the variant, with [`std::holds_alternative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in C++. What does & after auto do?

Comment: The value returned from `std::get` can either be a (deep) copy (`auto T1`), or a reference to the object held by the variant (`auto&`). In the latter case, if it is mutable, changes to the local variable (`myT`) will be reflected in the variant.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation!

Comment: `error: 'const' qualifier may not be applied to a reference`. East const has failed you.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat :D

Answer (score 1):

you can extract it either by index or by type and both will throw an exception if it is not the current active index or type

```
// by index
auto& str = std::get<0>(value);
// by type
auto& str = std::get<string>(value);
```

to check if the variant is holding a string you can check by index or type

```
// by index
bool is_str = value.index() == 0;
// by value
bool is_str = std::holds_alternative<string>(value);
```

Comment: searching by index is particularly useful if you have used the same type twice, which is allowed

Answer (score 1):

[`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is the preferred way to work with `std::variant`, you might do something like:

```cpp
std::string to_string(std::variant<std::string, int, float> var)
{
    return std::visit([]<typename T>(const T& e){
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
            return e;
        } else { // float/int
            return std::to_string(e);
        }
    }, var);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfa871855437e054)